# How to convert android native AbsoluteLayout to Xamarin.Forms.AbsoluteLayout

Tags: android, xamarin.android, absolutelayout

I have a video-call sdk which takes a `Xamarin.Forms.AbsoluteLayout` instance while initializing, so that it can place the video in that container.

I have separate UI for android and iOS.
In android I have a layout file (.axml) inside which there is an AbsoluteLayout.
I am accessing the AbsoluteLayout programmatically.
But I am getting compilation error on the second line of the code below,

```
[error: cannot convert type Android.View.View to Xamarin.Forms.AbsoluteLayout]

_view = activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Video, this, false);
var container = (Xamarin.Forms.AbsoluteLayout)_view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.container);
```

Although if I replace the typecast with `(Android.Widget.AbsoluteLayout)` no compilation error occurs.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, why do you want to do this?

Comment: The sdk I am using is built to use xaml based page. But we have separate UIs for iOS and Android. If we had a xaml page it would be easy to send Xamarin.Forms.AbsoluteLayout to the sdk as a container. But in our case we have an Android.Widget.AbsoluteLayout. :(

Comment: Are you trying to render the `Xamarin.Forms.AbsoluteLayout` in PCL to your custom layout (`Android.Widget.AbsoluteLayout`) in android platform?

Comment: No we don't have any xaml page so there is no `Xamarin.Forms.AbsoluteLayout` in PCL. The code snippet is in a `VideoCallPageRenderer : PageRenderer ` . It takes a layout file, inflates it and tries to get the AbsoluteLayout inside the layout file using `view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.container)`. `FindViewById` is returning  `Android.Widget.AbsoluteLayout`. Which needs to be converted to `(Xamarin.Forms.AbsoluteLayout`. Because the video call sdk takes a `Xamarin.Forms.AbsoluteLayout` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

android's **AbsoluteLayout** is in **Android.Widget** package, so change it:

```
var container = (Android.Widget.AbsoluteLayout)_view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.container);
```